# Change of space-time in Walsh's stochastic integral

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-calculus, martingales

One can read about Walsh's construction of martingale integral in the paper (pp.16-23)
http://www.math.utah.edu/~davar/ps-pdf-files/SPDEBookDK.pdf ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20180216162715/http://www.math.utah.edu/~davar/ps-pdf-files/SPDEBookDK.pdf))

For $U,V\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^+), \phi:U\to V$ is non-singular linear operator

I hope there was a formula like this:

$$
E\left|\iint_{\phi(U)}\xi(y,s)M(dy,ds)\right|^2=E\left|\iint_U \xi(\phi(x,t))|\det \phi|M(dx,dt)\right|^2
$$

or it's maybe more simple when $M$ is the 2-dimensional white noise (or Brownian sheet)

Answer (score 1):

In the case of white noise, if $\xi$ is deterministic, then
  \begin{align*}
  E\bigg|\iint_{\phi(U)}\xi(y,s)W(dy,ds)\bigg|^2
    &= E\bigg|\iint\xi(y,s)1_{\phi(U)}(y,s)W(dy,ds)\bigg|^2\\
  &= \iint|\xi(y,s)1_{\phi(U)}(y,s)|^2\,dy\,ds\\
  &= \iint_{\phi(U)}|\xi(y,s)|^2\,dy\,ds\\
  &= \iint_U |\xi(\phi(x,t))|^2\,|\det\phi|\,dx\,dt\\
  &= E\bigg|\iint_U \xi(\phi(x,t))\,|\det\phi|^{1/2}\,W(dx,dt)\bigg|^2.
  \end{align*}